# Application that receives data in real time without refresh

Tags: database, firebase, websocket, socket.io, real-time

I am developing a desktop program, a website and an application and they both communicate through the same database. I started researching about making these apps real-time, that I don't need to update to receive a new registration or a change to something. I discovered websockets and socket.io, saw some examples and read a lot about it, but then I saw that there are some databases that already do this and one of the most famous is firebase. What I would like to ask here is, using firebase can I make an application in real time? An application that when registering data to the database, all other connected applications receive this data in real time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In google firebase, you can create listeners on the client-side to respond to any changes in the backend. Check out https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen.

This is great if you need to store data, but if you are purely looking to send information between clients and there is no need for any persistence, I would recommend using WebSockets.

Comment: But how should I use realtime database or cloud firestore?

Comment: You could use firebase to make a real-time app by just updating the db whenever you need to send something to another client, and have the other client listen to any changes. This is not the best use of it though